# Recreate database+tables (it dosn't want to work with rake commands) ROR 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm newbie with ror and I just managed to ruin the  databse... I tried to recreate with this  2 methodes bu none works:

first:

```
rake db:reset
rake db:migrate
```

second:

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

But none work... I'm out of ideas what to do, please help...

My migrate folder is empty, if I migrate nothing happens, no table created notice.

Comment: Please define "ruined" and "doesn't work".

Comment: none of the rake whom pupose is to manipulate db... won't work

Comment: If you have your `schema.rb` you may use it. Try `rake db:schema:load`

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
rake db:migrate:reset
```

Comment: I just noticed you say the migrations folder is empty, if this is the case then you have nothing to migrate since migrations work on the files present on this folder. You will have to recreate your database from scratch :/

Comment: Check the contents of your schema.db file first, is there anything there?

Answer (score 0):

examine your database.yml file, it might default to SQLITE which is basically a text file.
Make sure you are using the correct database with the correct name.